# By what way is the light parted? Job 38:24

Tags: job

What answers do biblical scholars and scientists have regarding this subject?

Job 38:24 ASV

> **By what way is the light parted,** Or the east wind scattered upon the earth?

Comment: Some translation take it as lightning instead of light. e.g. NIV "What is the way to the place where the lightning is dispersed,"

Comment: I don’t know that divided is quite how we would translate it today in modern English. If the word בּדל had been used divided would be appropriate but חלק is used and חלק can accurately be translated to divide but it probably should have been translated dispersed, scattered or distributed in modern English. So while divided has the connotation to separate by splitting, distributed has the connotation of blanketing. Job was being asked if he knew the behavior of light, its characteristics and its properties and not necessarily how it behaves but why it behaves the way it behaves.

Answer (score 3):

Job 38 contains a series of God's rhetorical questions that are supposed to be unanswerable and thus, illustrate the vast superiority of divine wisdom over man's knowledge.

In Job 38:24 we have the question:

> Where is the way that the light is divided

This may be an allusion to Gen 1:4 of creation week where God divided/separated the light from darkness, but this is not essential to understanding the rhetorical question.  It simply shows how limited man's knowledge is about many things.

[ NOTE: some versions translate V24 is involving "lightning" but this is a mistake.  The word used in V24 is אוֹר (or) and is always translated "light".  Another word בָּרָק (baraq) is translated "lightning" and actually occurs in Job 38:35, "*Can you send the lightning bolts on their way? Do they report to you, ‘Here we are’?*" ]

Thus, no answer to the questions is Job 38 is required except that given by Job himself in two places following God's questions:

> Job 40:4, 5 - “Behold, I am insignificant. How can I reply to You? I
> place my hand over my mouth. I have spoken once, but **I have no answer**—
> twice, but I have nothing to add.”
>
> Job 42:4-6 - You said, ‘Listen now, and I will speak. I will question
> you, and you shall inform Me.’ My ears had heard of You, but now my
> eyes have seen You. Therefore **I retract my words**, and I repent in dust
> and ashes.”

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 38

> 1 Then the Lord spoke to Job out of the storm. He said:
>
> 2 “Who is this that obscures my plans
> with words without knowledge?
> 3 Brace yourself like a man;
> I will question you,
> and you shall answer me.

In this chapter God is asking Job a series of poetic rhetorical questions to drive home the point that God is sovereign.

> 22 “Have you entered the storehouses of the snow
> or seen the storehouses of the hail,
> 23 which I reserve for times of trouble,
> for days of war and battle?
> **24 What is the way to the place where the lightning is dispersed,
>
> or the place where the east winds are scattered over the earth?**
> 25 Who cuts a channel for the torrents of rain,
> and a path for the thunderstorm,
> 26 to water a land where no one lives,
> an uninhabited desert,
> 27 to satisfy a desolate wasteland
> and make it sprout with grass?

The answer to the question posed in verse 22 is "no but God has"

The answer to the question in verse 24 "What is the way to the place where lightning is dispersed, or the place where the east winds are scattered over the earth?" is Job does not know - but God does.

Verse 25 "who cuts a channel for the torrents of rain and a parth for the thunderstorm" the answer - God does

Verse 26 "to water a land where no one lives, an uninhabited desert" - the answer God does

The pattern is throughout the chapter and runs on into chapter 39

Verse 24 is a small part of the larger point that God is in control of everything and Job is not.

This point fits into the larger story of Job.